# Check which part of string is not split

Tags: c#, regex

Can we check which part of a string is not split?

For example, if I try to split `i=0 i<5;i++`, then I want it to display that there is a `;` missing after `i=0`.

Here's my code:

```
List<string> names = textBox1.Text.Split(';').ToList<string>();
```

Comment: Split on space and `;`

Comment: I think you would need some sort of parser, in general, to detect syntax problems in a code.

Comment: Is there any by which we can split those strings which are not splitted with implementation of parser

Comment: do you just want to look for missing semicolon after i=0 or it could be after i<5 as well?

Comment: Thanks it solved my problem. And kindly upvote my question. As stackoverflow has stopped me to ask new questions due negative reputation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the Fiddle link to test, it is not an elegant way but it serves your purpose
https://dotnetfiddle.net/QaQE0s

The better way probably would be to make an expression syntax and then check for syntax errors

Comment: Thanks it solved my problem. And kindly upvote my question. As stackoverflow has stopped me to ask new questions due negative reputation.

Comment: @Jahanzaib Niazi, i am unable to upvote u as i need more than 125 reputations to do that